# Issue in promoting app from beta to production

Tags: android, html, beta

I had uploaded an app to Beta and had a few users test it, it was fine and later I moved it to production and it got published as well. After it got published, it isn't working. This is the error it shows:

[image: This is the error that it shows]

> Cannot open the html file 'http://localhost:0/':
>   uriPort <= 0: 0 (http://localhost:0/)

What do I do?

Comment: When do you get this error? What are you trying to do when this occurs.

Comment: When I open the app. Any user who opens the app will see this screen,You can check the app here-
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beluga.ww2